# As soon as possible vs as early as possible

Tags: phrase-usage, time

What is the difference between "as soon as possible" and "as early as possible"?

I want to say:

> I'll release it as soon as possible
>
> I'll release it as early as possible

"As early as possible" sounds wrong to me but I am not sure. Is it correct to use "as early as possible" in this sentence or not?

Comment: Aside.  The first kinda looks like ASAP a common abbreviation.  I once thought it meant "right now" but after waiting for a parts order for some days, discovered, at least in procurement, that it means as soon as possible after the important stuff is done.  The word they wanted in my "rush" case was the word "expedite".  I do think ASAP does still mean goose it in many quarters thou.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As early as possible would be relative to a time period such as early spring or early that day or early that year.

Whereas "soon" just indicates in the near future relative from now.

Comment: The time period could just be "from 'now' on"; 'as early as possible' is often used with the meaning 'as soon as possible', though it could be used for a different time period ('We'll arrive next Monday, as early as possible'). Obviously, any other time period than 'from now on' will need context to specify it. Without that, the period defaults to 'from now on'.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that my following explanations of either phrase can be reversed for each other, but this is what I gather upon immediately hearing each of the phrases.

**I'll release it as soon as possible.**

The person may not adhere to a strict dead-line, but may have some personal constraints preventing the release.

**I'll release it as early as possible.**

The person may be adhering to some dead-line that does not allow them to release it *beforehand*.